# How to allow icons in title?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to allow icons to be added in my title when entered into the database. I currently get an error message saying:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value:
'\xF0\x9F\x94\xA5 F...' for column 'title' at row 1
(SQL: insert into `media` (`title`, `created_at`)
values (Yosemite Fire  Falls, 2017-03-16 18:50:56))
```

What changes do I need to make to the database in order to allow these type of icons? (icons that are for example entered through the iOS/macOS keyboard)

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: I use Laravel as my framework and I simply enter it via: `$media = $request->create($request->all());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need [`utf8mb4` encoding](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) for any columns which need to encode emoji data. You may need to `ALTER TABLE` to achieve this.